# Coreplot: Axis Labels Fixed Location

Tags: core-plot

I'm trying to customize a Coreplot graph in many ways I can and the next thing I would like to do is place the X Axis Labels (one that is custom as well) at the bottom of the graph, independent of the X axis' position (whether it's scrolled up or down).

To make it clear, it is similar to giving the labels an offset value of something like 50.0. But offset is not the property I'm looking for since it fixes the labels location relative to the X axis.

Any way this can be done? Or do I have to skip the `axisLabels` property and place and layer or something manually at the bottom of the graph?

EDIT: Alright, I managed to place an axis on the bottom with `CPTConstraints`. But it's not on the bottommost. If a plot point is on those levels, the plot line overlaps the labels. I tired padding of the graph but of course, it moves the whole graph, hence the issue persists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that aside from the graph, the `plotAreaFrame` property of the `CPTGrpah` also has paddings. If you give more paddings to `plotAreaFrame` than that of the `graph`, the plot will be drawn in a smaller frame and the rest of the graph area will be for you to add what you want (i.e., a second Axis).

Big thanks to @Eric, for trying to answer Every single CorePlot question as soon as possible.

CorePlot does have a lot of customisation than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Make a second x-axis. Have the first one draw the axis line, tick marks, etc., as normal but no labels. Label the second one and set all of the line style properties to `nil` so it doesn't draw any of the lines.

Comment: Ok I'll try that out. But how should I position the second axis? I want it to be always on the bottom, even when the plot scrolls. It should stay on the bottom like a background axis label.

Comment: Use constraints, e.g., `x2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];`

Comment: Hi @Eric, as I mentioned in my edit, I already used constraints. But the axis is not moving past the graph space. I'm looking for a way to put to axis on the bottombost so there isn't the possibility of axis labels overlapping plot lines. I'd appreciate if you refer to my edit and offer something I'm missing.