# coreplot xaxis offset for placing the labels at the right place

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to plot a graph with core plot framework, the problem is i want to pin the x axis labels to the bottom of the graph, i can change the xAxis.labelOffset value but the problem is that my y range can be variable. So is there a way to calculate the offset on the fly or any other way of pinning the x labels at the bottom.

I tried something like this but its not working

```
float height = self.hostingView.bounds.size.height/2;

float offset = height*ABS(minimumValue)/60;

xAxis.labelOffset = offset;`
```

Comment: Do you want to pin the x-axis, too, or just the labels?

Comment: i want to pin the x-axis labels only so that they remain visible at the bottom on the graph

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coreplot: Axis Labels Fixed Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746619/coreplot-axis-labels-fixed-location)